# Android Studios Serialization. Attempt to get length of null array

Tags: android, serialization, permissions

Okay, so in my project I am trying to serialize a chess game by writing to a folder named data. I did this in eclipse, and it was able to work. However, when I brought it into android studios I got the error of trying to get the length of a null array. Here is my method:

```
public static void writeData() throws IOException {

    System.out.println("WRiting data");
    File folder = new File("data" + File.separator);
    folder.mkdir();
    String[] directories = folder.list(); 

    for (String name : directories) { //error here
        File ff = new File(folder + File.separator + name);
        if (ff.isDirectory()) {
            deleteDirectory(ff);
        }
    }

    //add all user data
    for (game u : info.games) {

        File f = new File("data" + File.separator + u.name);            //make a file with user name

        f.mkdir(); //make the file a directory

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(f + File.separator + "game-state"));

        //create stream with file name at the end

        oos.writeObject(u);

        //write objects
        oos.close();
    }

}
```

Also, I looked at previous questions and changed my manifest file to allow for the permissions of writing and reading data.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The app does not crash when I read data. However, it crashes when I try to write data. Going crazy over here. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The manifest changes I have are <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to marshmellow permission request ,you have to call permission request at runtime .
go through link
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html